# How to enable cryptocell on nrf5340

Tags: zephyr-rtos, nordic-semi, nrf5-sdk, nrf53

I built an tf_m zephyr image that runs tfm_ipc application with following west command:

```
west build -p always -b nrf5340dk_nrf5340_cpuapp_ns samples/tfm_integration/tfm_ipc/
```

After flashing it to my nrf5340 board through `nrfjprog  -f nrf53 -r --program built_images_nrf5340/tfm_ipc/tfm_merged.hex`, I figured cryptocell-312 accelerator is not enabled by default. I would like to know how I could enable it.

Thank you!

I tried using menuconfig option by:

```
west build -p always -b nrf5340dk_nr f5340_cpuapp_ns samples/tfm_integration/tfm_ipc/ -t menuconfig
```

But it does not allow me to toggle `DT_HAS_ARM_CRYPTOCELL_312_ENABLED`

[menufconfig interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSJET.png)

I also see this in Kconfig.dts file in build directory after build.
[Kconfig.dts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH484.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use the nRF Connect SDK:
Enabling of Cryptocell for cryptographic operations with the nRF5340 depends on which crypto libvrary you are using. The default crypto library is the PSA Crypto library. In this case, you can use CONFIG_PSA_CRYPTO_DRIVER_CC3XX to enable the Cryptocell.